# Using Update, Delete and Insert Statements in a single Stored Procedure on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario that requires me to firstly set a range of column values in a table to Null, then I add the logic to re-calculate the new `NULL` values with an `Update` statement following the previous `Update` statement. Lastly I run my final comparison script (within a cursor) which inserts the new values into a table.

Do I need to use the `GO` command between each major command?

Example:

```
Drop Table1

Update Table2
Set Col1=NULL,Col2=NULL

Insert into Table3 (Col1,Col2)
```

Is using a `GO` between each statement a requirement as sometimes this works but lately it's been giving me issues?

Thanks,

Comment: `GO` isn't a SQL Server statement and cannot appear within a stored procedure. It's the (default) batch delimiter that some/most of the SQL Server *client* tools recognize, and use to split what they're sending *to* SQL Server into separate batches.

Comment: Why do you think you need a curser?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `GO` is not an SQL syntax, but SSMS separator.

If you really need to perform all those actions in the single SP, you can use a dynamic SQL. The're two abilities to execute dynamic SQL in the SQL server" [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [execute (command)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Additional information according to the dynamic SQL can be found here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html or here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

In this case your script will be like following:

```
create proc myProc
as
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'Drop Table1';
exec sp_executesql @sql;

set @sql = N'Update Table2
Set Col1=NULL,Col2=NULL';
exec sp_executesql @sql;

set @sql = N'Insert into Table3 (Col1,Col2)';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
go
```

But need to check if you really need to perform the above operations in the mentioned above manner...